# Why my angular code is not rendering anything on the screen

Tags: angular

> I have an input field. I want to print on the screen in real time anything that i type in.
>
> The code below prints 'Hello world' with an input field. But does not performs any real time binding.
>
> File: app.component.html

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<input type="text">
```

> But the moment I add `[(ngModule)]`. Everything vanishes even the Hello world. Though the cmd prompt says Compiled successfully.

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

> My app.component.ts file is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
}
```

[I have also uploaded my code on GitHub for your convenience](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/angular-first-app)

Comment: Angular isn't a native JS framework : you have to install it in its entirety. 

You can't just create 3 files and expect it to work like that ...

Comment: I know. I've created a fresh project using 'ng new' command. But I uploaded only the relevant files. Anyways, someone has answered the question. Chears.!!

Comment: Well for your next question, consider providing **your full code** and not just the one you think is the issue. Consider making a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com (online VSCode), as it will greatly help us help you. Glad your issue is resolved though, see you around !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import `FormsModule` in **app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ]
```

I think you have missed to add all the files in GitHub

Comment: Uploaded app.module.ts just now